# Starting a Rails 5 project with Devise and Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, devise

I'm trying to create a Rails 5 API with admin views using mongodb and devise for auth. I know the process can go a lot smoother if everything is set up correctly from the beginning. What sort of terminal commands would I need to run to specify to rails what to leave out and what to add in?

i.e. `rails new myapp --no-activerecord --db=mongodb --with-devise`

There's one tutorial online but its Rails 3 from 2012.

Comment: `rails new myapp --skip-active-record --database=mongodb`. I have not used _with_devise_ anytime in my projects. For more information you can run `rails` command and it'll return all the possible options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the description mentioned in the post, please follow the below mentioned points:

Create a new project using below mentioned command

```
rails new name_of_the_project --skip-active-record

name_of_the_project = specify the name which you want to keep
--skip-active-record = this will skip loading active-record as an ORM.
```

Then you need to add mongoid to the gemfile, so that rails can know you want to use it as an ORM

```
gem 'mongoid', '~> 6.2.0'
```

After adding , then run following command

```
bundle install
rails g mongoid:config
```

The last command configures, mongoid such as generating mongoid.yml.

Hope this answers your question.